# show Jquery tooltip onclick of textbox insted of mousehover

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Jquery tooltip.
How can i display tooltip onclick of textbox insted of mouseover.
what css have use to display tooltip arrow at center(for second textbox) for second textbox its moving down.

**HTML**

```
<br/><br/>
<input id="ag22" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." />

<br/><br/>
<input id="ag22" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "left center",
        at: "right center",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
            $(this).css(position);
            $("<div>")
                .addClass("arrow")
                .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                .appendTo(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the link i have tried:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/b7SCN/

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `trigger` to simulate the mouseover when you click like in this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AK7pv/

After you can't add two element with the same `ID`, use `CLASS` to have multiple element

Check on this subject : [jQueryUI tooltip Widget to show tooltip on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753458/jqueryui-tooltip-widget-to-show-tooltip-on-click)

Comment: `+1` for being funny,

Comment: I have add source :).

Comment: @DonovanCharpin:need to close tooltip if click on any where.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin: In the first link you have use another div to display tooltip but i am trying to use it for title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do anything on `mouseover`, add this before initializing tooltip. You might have to disable `focusin` also

```
$('input').on('mouseover',function(e) {
    e.preventdefault();
});
```

trigger tooltip open on click

```
$('input').on('click',function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip('open');
});
```

Edit : Change `$(document).tooltip` to `$('input').tooltip`

Comment: Change $(document).tooltip to $('input').tooltip. It will work

Comment: @ChaitanyaMunipalle:It work for click ,but when i hovermouse on textbox its show difault title tootlip.

Comment: As per this question, It is showing tooltip on click instead of mouseover. You have to figure out a hack to not display default title, there are many hacks for that in stackoverflow itself.