# Jquery UI tooltip - multiple tooltips

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI for my tooltips. I would like to have more than one on the same page and have them open and close on click. I found a solution for having them open on click:
http://jsfiddle.net/rjGeS/83/
(taken from this link -> [jQueryUI tooltip Widget to show tooltip on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753458/jqueryui-tooltip-widget-to-show-tooltip-on-click))

What I need help with is having multiple tooltips on one page.

I tried altering the code slightly to make it work, but its just opening them all

```
$('#tooltip_1').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);

$(".tooltip").html(function() {
    $('.ttip').css({
        left: $this.position() + '20px',
        top: $this.position() + '50px'
    }).show()

}).fadeIn();

});

$('#tooltip_2').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);

$(".tooltip").html(function() {
    $('.ttip').css({
        left: $this.position() + '20px',
        top: $this.position() + '50px'
    }).show()

}).fadeIn();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code you've posted actually has nothing to do with [jQueryUI Tooltips](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), I'll give a clean example instead.

You can use the `open()` and `close()` functions to show and hide tooltips programmatically. If you also need to stop the default tooltip functionality (as in, showing them on `mouseover` events) the easy way to do that is to use the `disabled` option.

Since you didn't specify if this should be click-once-show-all or not, here's a fiddle doing it for all: http://jsfiddle.net/wuL9M/ and here's a fiddle doing it individually: http://jsfiddle.net/qnYRy/

Note this line:

```
    $(".tooltip").off("mouseleave focusout");
```

It disables the default closing behaviour while the tooltip is open.

If you want to partially preserve only **some** of the default tooltip functionality, you can use a custom flag (instead of the `disabled` option), or you can attach extra event handlers to `tooltipopen` and `tooltipclose`. [It's all pretty well documented here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

ADD: You can use the `content` option to customise the tooltip with any (potentially non-static) data. eg: http://jsfiddle.net/qnYRy/1/ You can change it after initialisation with the `option` function:

```
$("#myTooltip").tooltip("option", "content", "My updated tooltip data");
$("#myTooltip").tooltip("option", "content", function() { return "My updated tooltip data"; });
```

For obvious reasons this would require you to set the content for each tooltip separately. Also note that it will ignore any html `title` attribute you may have.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I didn't realize what I was using had nothing to do with jquery ui. The thing I really like about what I'm using is that it allows for custom content. I need to put a table within the tooltip to give more information on fees. Is there a way this can be done with your solution?

Comment: @michelle Yes, you can use the `content` option to customise the tooltip, well, content. eg. http://jsfiddle.net/qnYRy/1/ I'll add that to the answer.