# How to transform a DOM element into a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I want to transform an already existing `div` element in a tooltip that stays open until dismissed. I tried to use JQuery official [tooltip plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/). I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926904/1763602) to not close it on mouseleave, but it requires a content string, I can't pass a DOM element.

Even if [there's a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734408/1763602) to pass HTML content, I need the original DOM element, since events are binded to it.

qTip2 seems to be able to do it, but [elements must be adjacent](http://qtip2.com/guides#content.element) and they can't.

For now I've done it by hand, but I'm not sure I'm covering all the subtle possibilities of a bad positioning. And furthermore it looks ugly.

Comment: What events could make sense when bound to a tooltip element? I mean, you can't click or hover it, so what's the point?

Comment: About the close requests: It's on-topic to ask a question about a specific tool. It's off-topic to ask a question for recommendations.

Comment: @TomášZato: I want a tooltip that opens only on click and stay opened. I found a way to do it with the jQuery plugin, but the above problem remains.

Comment: @Reeno: not asking recommendetions. I'm not asking "What's the best tool for...", but I'm asking for a tool for a very specific problem. If this question is off-topic, every question that are like "Is there a way in language X to do Y" is off-topic.

Comment: @Reeno: ok, I think you're referring to the point #4 of the guidelines. I edited the title.

Comment: Something that opens on click and stays opened is not a tooltip. So I guess you are still on your way to figure out what is it youa ctually want.

Comment: @TomášZato: see for example http://qtip2.com/demos#section-events , first field

Comment: That's not on click though, you're little bit confusing, but now I understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out you can, sort of, do this in jQuery UI using `open` and `close` events. Basically what you do is connect your element to existing UI. I figured this out by **[reading the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open)**, you could do this as well.

```
$("#tooltip").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        // Return nothing here, because only strings are accepted
        return " ";
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        var element = ... create or get element here ...;
        ui.tooltip[0].appendChild(element);
    },
    close: function( event, ui ) {
        // Destroy the element? 
    }
});
```

I created a jsFiddle where `<input` gets teleported from `<body>` to tooltip:

https://jsfiddle.net/kujo54cq/1/